# Richbox doesn't update while method is running

Tags: c#, winforms

Sorry for the inappropriate title. I have program as below

```
int status = 100;
richTextBox1.AppendText("Starting Process....." + "\n");

status = comm.WriteData(cmd1);
if (status == 0)
{
    richTextBox1.AppendText("COMMAND 1 OK" + "\n");
}
else
{
    richTextBox1.AppendText("COMMAND 1 NOT OK" + "\n");
}
richTextBox1.AppendText("Gathering signal from product sensor....." + "\n");
status = comm.WriteData(cmd2);
if (status == 0)
{
    richTextBox1.AppendText("COMMAND 2 OK" + "\n");
}
else
{
    richTextBox1.AppendText("COMMAND 2 NOT OK" + "\n");
}
richTextBox1.AppendText("Measuring current value" + "\n");
status = comm.WriteData(cmd3);
if (status == 0)
{
    richTextBox1.AppendText("COMMAND 3 OK" + "\n");
}
else
{
    richTextBox1.AppendText("COMMAND 3 NOT OK" + "\n");
}
```

This will execute on a button click event. Like this I need to send 130 commands. The overall process takes almost 6 minutes. The code works fine. But until the execution of all commands (for 6 minutes), the `RichTextBox` appears to be empty. After execution of each command I need to display message to operator whether the command is OK or NOT OK. I even tried by giving delay between each command. but can't achieve what I need. Please support to resolve this.

Comment: What code do you have in WriteData(cmd)? you can make it async and await it where you call it.

Comment: its an ASCII value to a instrument via serial port communication

Comment: I've taken the freedom to edit your title to actually match the question

Comment: Perfect. thanks for helping me out with the title & code. Am trying with your code

Comment: can you please let me know how to handle reentrance event?

Comment: @Vasanth I've added one of the many possible ways to handle it

Comment: got it. thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a `BackgroundWorker` here, and use `ReportProgress` to add to the textbox. Something like (off my mind):

```
public void ButtonClick()
{
   // Since your code will now be async, you should need to handle reentrance here
   var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
   worker.ReportsProgress = true;
   worker.ProgressChanged += ProgressLog;
   worker.DoWork += TestComm;
   worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void ProgressLog(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
   richTextBox1.AppendText(e.UserState.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
}

private void TestComm(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{         
   var worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
   worker.ReportProgress(0, "Starting Process.....");
   // Sub-optimal way to construct a string :-)
   worker.ReportProgress(0, "COMMAND 1 " + (comm.WriteData(cmd1) == 0 ? "OK" : "NOT OK"));
   worker.ReportProgress(0, "Gathering signal from product sensor.....");
   worker.ReportProgress(0, "COMMAND 2 " + (comm.WriteData(cmd2) == 0 ? "OK" : "NOT OK"));
   worker.ReportProgress(0, "Measuring current value");
   worker.ReportProgress(0, "COMMAND 3 " + (comm.WriteData(cmd3) == 0 ? "OK" : "NOT OK"));
   // etc.
}
```

As a side note, if all you do is "show a header string", "run command", write "command # ok/not ok", this could be easily refactored into a loop, but I'll leave that to you :-)

Also, since your code would now be asynchronous, you'd need to handle reentrance to the button's `Click` event, since a user could now click the button while the test is running (and thus would run two tests simultaneously, which, if you are using comm ports, might not be possible).

This could be as simple as disabling the button when you create the worker, and enabling it again on the `BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted` event, or you could complicate it as much as you want (cancelling the initial test and starting it again, or whatnot).

As stated on the comments, you also need help with the reentrance. The simplest way would be something like:

```
public void ButtonClick()
{
   // Disable the button       
   myButton.Enabled = false;

   var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
   worker.ReportsProgress = true;
   worker.ProgressChanged += ProgressLog;
   worker.DoWork += TestComm;

   // Re-enable the button when the worker has completed (or failed)
   worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (o,e) => myButton.Enabled = true;
   worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to write your data in a separate thread. What's happening is your UI thread is waiting for execution of your function to finish before resuming normal operations like updating controls. You can read more in the documentation for winforms's [BackgroundWorker Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx?ppud=4).

Answer (score 1):

try this code after each AppendText:

```
richTextBox1.Refresh();
```

Comment: While this will work, so would `Application.DoEvents()`, but I'd never ethically recommend this (or `DoEvents`) when there are other much better solutions :-)